# How to insert a ListItem in On-Premise deployed sharepoint 2013 list using .net core API

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, sharepoint-2013, core-api

I have Sharepoint 2013 hosted on-premise. I have a list in there, into which I need to insert records from a .net core API. How do I do this? Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Hi @zaitsman, I tried this for on-premise, [link](http://www.whypad.com/posts/authenticate-sharepoint-rest-call-in-a-rest-client/1169/). It says 401 Unauthorized when trying to get FormDigest. Also I looked into this link, [link](https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/), But I guess that is for Sharepoint online as it requires registration of Application. On the API side, I have my API code following this article, [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-items-into-a-sharepoint-list-programmatically-using-c/). It returns the same 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: You need to check with your Sharepoint administrator how the authentication is setup on your Sharepoint. It may be using forms, basic, digest, client cert auth or even a third party SSO. You can't code an appropriate method unless you set up your sharepoint and/or you know how the auth is set up.

Comment: Hi @zaitsman, yes, it is configured to use Active Directory authentication. I tried it as well to get 400 Bad Request. One question, does Microsoft.SharePoint.Client work in .net core 3 apis? I have brought its reference from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585